# declare array 2^32 size in 32bit OS

Tags: c#, hash

I want to  declare array 2^32 size on 32 bit OS for integer hash table.tell me what to do?
It is giving me Out of memory exception.

Comment: Would be great to see some code or atleast tell us why you need a table of that size

Answer (score 2):

You simply can't do this. In a 32-bit CLR, all objects must be less than 2GB in size.

Even in a 64-bit CLR, you have to specify a special flag to enable larger arrays ([`<gcAllowVeryLargeObjects>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054.aspx)) - and if your array is an array of integers, you're actually asking for 16GB. It seems unlikely that you'd have that much physical memory on a 32-bit OS.

You can work around the limit to some extent by making one "logical" array composed of multiple smaller arrays, but I rarely view that as a good idea. Basically, you should either redesign or use an OS that's more suitable for your requirements. I suspect that a redesign is likely to be the best approach.

Comment: +1. "unlikely to have 16GB on 32 bit OS" is way too nice... You actually can't do that at all (ignoring indirect solutions like [PAE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366796%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Things like PAE were why I didn't want to claim it to be absolutely impossible ;)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Yup, no problem. I'd like to think I have a *reasonably* thick skin, and this wasn't even a tickle ;)